# Mysqld can`t start after I changed the socket path

Tags: mysql, permissions

here is the log

```
131229 14:55:27 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
131229 14:55:27 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /tmp/mysql.sock ?
```

and what i had down is this in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
socket =/tmp/mysql.sock
```

what to put the sock file in here and tmp

```
drwxrwxrwt.  15 root root  4096 Dec 29 14:55 tmp
```

But I can start it anymore, if I remove that `/tmp/mysql.sock`. every think is ok.
why?
why tmp got a 777 permission but it still got this error?
thinks in advance.

Comment: Looks like 4096 port is already taken. Hav you tried another ones ?

Comment: @HAL9000 If it were already taken the error would be "Socket already in use"

Comment: @Barmar yes, but second error log message means, that socket is busy, no?

Comment: The second error message is just generic, it prints it regardless of the error it got trying to open the socket.

Comment: What is the ownership and permissions on `/tmp/mysql.sock`? It needs to be owned by the userid that runs `mysqld`.

Comment: @Barmar there is no mysql.sock file in folder /tmp, how can i create is ?

Answer (score 2):

When everything you can think of to check seems right, you have to think of the things you can't think of. :)

Like possibly "apparmor."

https://askubuntu.com/questions/234668/cant-start-mysql-server-if-the-sock-file-is-changed-in-etc-mysql-my-cnf

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor